# Cms for free temple bootstrap website

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, content-management-system

I recently downloaded news reporter free website template for my localhost. I am using WAMP server for my host. I am looking for cms to manage that host such as news post or delete post. Sorry for my bad English

Justin

Answer (score 0):

One of the most popular CMS' is wordpress.org and you can run that on a local server with WAMP, or you can runs bitnami's wordpress plugin with XAMPP making things even easier. Wordpress has more resources than probably anything else like it.

Another popular CMS is [Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/releases/8.0.0), this can just be downloaded and unzipped straight into your \www folder in WAMP and will give you an interface inwhich you can configure the CMS. Drupal, although not as popular, has great documentation and lots of third party plugins and modules.